# equals to comparison not working even though the values are same

Tags: php, equals-operator

Here is the php code where am comparing the two values. The courses values are what I passed from controller that is coming from the database and prev_course has the value previously selected. Though the comparison becomes same for one time it showing the else part of code every time. As you can see the 3rd output is same GRE and GRE but still showing not same

> The output of the code comes like this

```
not same
prev course= GRE and from db=IELTS
not same 
prev course= GRE and from db=TOFELS
not same 
prev course= GRE and from db=GRE
```

**here is the php code for comparison I have tried both == and ===**

```
<?php foreach($instructor_course as $courses):?>
    <?php if($courses['name']===$prev_course):?>
    <?php echo 'same<br/>';?><?php echo "prev course=$prev_course"." and from db=".$courses['name'] ."<br/>";?>

    <?php else: ?>
<?php echo 'not same <br/>';?><?php echo "prev course=$prev_course"." and from db=".$courses['name'] ."<br/>";?>
<?php endif;?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: @PaulCrovella Add your comment as an answer please so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
foreach($instructor_course as $courses) {
    if($courses['name'] === trim($prev_course)) {
        echo 'same<br/>';
        echo "prev course=$prev_course and from db=$courses['name']<br/>";
    } else {
        echo 'not same <br/>';
        echo "prev course=$prev_course and from db=$courses['name'] <br/>";
    }
}
```